# flushing audio buffer in html

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a jsp page with a record button which records and saves a wave file, and a play button.

My problem is when I am playing the wave file using audio tag in html, the latest recorded file does not play. Instead the first file recorded after the page loads is played.

My script for playing:

#### JavaScript

```
function play() {
    var thissound="http://localhost:8084/ProjectName/"+'${cookie.JSESSIONID.value}'+".wav";

    document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio=document.createElement("audio");
    audio.setAttribute("preload","none");
    audio.setAttribute("autoplay","true");
    audio.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
    audio.setAttribute('src',thissound);

}
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play();"></input>
```

Comment: You  don't use the element "audio1". so you can remove it from the code. plus check thissound value with console.log(thissound); to see if it is changing with the required sound file when invoke the play method.

Comment: you are not setting the attribute to audio1 element. you are setting the attribute to the newly created element called audio.

Comment: Yes sir you are right.I must comment this line document.getElementById('audio1');after commenting it the problem remains the same. For the session id part the record button is saving file named as sessionid.wav & the wave file is getting updated as i have confirmed it by playing it with some player

Comment: did you confirm (thissound) variable using alert or console.log() whether it is changing with the audio file name that you want, when the command play() invokes?

Comment: yes sir i have confirmed the value of thissound variable with alert its value is changing correctly when the command play() is invoked.

Comment: once you create an element, it will be there till you refresh the browser. So  when you are creating the audio element, check whether there is already an element called audio. If it is there reset it, and set attrib(s). else create it as a new element and set the attrib(s) and check. else you can place the audio element and call it with JS. no need to create it.